# How to choose value of x and y using pandas dataframe in Python based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe df:

```
| a| b| c|    
| 4| 6| 8|
| 2| 3| 1|
```

My aim is to split the dataframe into x and y such that for every x I choose, whole dataframe columns are considered except one which can be further used as y and so on. This is repeated till the last column has been used as y.

I want to know how can i define x and y and then apply my condition?

**Condition:**

How to choose the value of x and y such that for

step1: x=df[b], df[c] and y =df[a]

Step2: x=df[a], df[c] and y= df[b]

Step3: x=df[a], df[b] and y= df[c]
and then apply some condition?

P.S- the logic I want to use is, for every x all the values of the dataframe is considered except one which will be used as y. Thank you in advance

Comment: If you show the input and output dataframe you would get more help - it seems a little confusing what you are aiming for.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example?

Comment: I have edited my question, I just want to know how I can define x and y in such a case based on the above condition. Thanks a lot

Comment: still can't understand.

Comment: that does not help - create a dataframe that you are starting with, and then show some iterations on what you say. Because as it stands you seem to want an integer `x` that equals `df['b'] == d['c']` and a `y` that equals `df['a']`  and iterate .

Comment: [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html). `x = df[['a','b']]; y=df['c']`...